# Add new field to content type programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

I created a content type in Drupal programmatically with the following code:

```
function reservation_system_node_info() {
  $items['add_item'] = array(
    'name' => t('Add a new item'),
    'type' => 'add_item',
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'has_title' => '1',
    'title_label' => t('Name'),
    'help' => t('Please fill in all fields.'),
  );
}
```

Now I want to add some fields into this content type, but with no luck. I hope someone can help me with this. I tried to use the `system_create_instance()` function from Drupal. The code I used:

```
function reservation_system_create_instance() {
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'price_item',
    'label' => 'Price',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'add_item',
  );

field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

Should I use an another function to create fields in a content type or do I mis something?

Comment: You can try to use mechanism, which using in module features

Comment: where is the `hook_field_info` ?

Comment: Thank you @Eugene, the module features works perfect for me!